# ¿Son condicionales las oraciones que comienzan por "¿Y si..."?

Tags: subjuntivo, sintaxis

En el análisis de las frases que tengo que hacer, tengo algunas frases que empiezan con *y si* + *subjuntivo imperfecto*.

por ej.:

> a) ¿Y si en esta carpeta guardara algo importante?
>
> b) ¿Y si enviara una carta a Londres?
>
> c) ¿Y si tuviéramos suerte y descubriéramos una nueva pista?

¿Se puede decir que estas oraciones son oraciones condicionales sin la oración principal?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la Nueva Gramática, [apartado 47.3q](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SGXNqgLzATlOIWXl) se tratan este tipo de oraciones:

> Se asimilan a las condicionales suspendidas las interrogativas encabezadas por la conjunción *y* en las que se propone algo, como en *¿Y si lo dejamos para otro día?* [...]. En otras prótasis suspendidas se conjetura la posibilidad de que pueda darse algún hecho o sea cierto algún estado de cosas, como en *¿Y si estuviéramos todos equivocados?* [...].

Pone como ejemplos las siguientes frases:

> - ¿Y si ella se niega a dármelo y quedo desairado?
> - ¿Y si aún quisiera oponerse a vuestros amores?
> - ¿Y si te jurase que nada pasará?

Así que sí, las oraciones son **[condicionales suspendidas](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnzIYtZggtvDmgAD)**. Si así lo ves más claro, en todas estas frases y en las de tu pregunta, la conjunción *y* se podría sustituir por *qué pasaría*:

- ¿Qué pasaría si en esta carpeta guardara algo importante?
- ¿Qué pasaría si enviara una carta a Londres?
- ¿Qué pasaría si tuviéramos suerte y encontráramos una nueva pista?

Answer (score 2):

Todas son condicionales porque conllevan una reacción la cual no sabes hasta que no la ejecutes.

Este tipo es oración condicional real según el DPD 1ª edición que dice lo siguiente:

> Reales». Se denominan así porque la condición expresada es un hecho
>   posible o realizable. El verbo de la prótasis va en indicativo, en
>   cualquiera de sus tiempos, salvo en el futuro simple o futuro, futuro
>   compuesto o antefuturo, condicional simple o pospretérito y
>   condicional compuesto o antepospretérito; el verbo de la apódosis va
>   en indicativo o en imperativo: Si llueve, me quedaré en casa; Si no
>   hacías lo que él decía, se enfadaba; Si vas a salir, ponte el abrigo.
>   En el lenguaje administrativo se conserva aún el uso arcaico en la
>   prótasis de los tiempos futuros de subjuntivo: Si no se presentare el
>   escrito en el plazo indicado, el demandante perderá sus derechos; Si
>   el solicitante no hubiere acreditado suficientemente sus méritos, se
>   considerará inválida su petición.

Se puede omitir perfectamente el "Y", que la frase sigue siendo condicional.

Si enviara esa carta a londres....
 Si lloviera mañana...

Enlace: http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=uqFr1XT7vD6KF3oDZL

Comment: Claramente, el uso que citas no es el de la pregunta: "el verbo de la prótasis va en indicativo", mientras que en las de la pregunta es subjuntivo.